# Check or folders recursively, but skip a particular one

Tags: java, recursion, directory

Ok, I have a pretty common function to check all files from a path (including sub-folders). In the given path I have multiple folders, like Folder1, Folder2, Folder3... Foldern, and I want to skip Folder2 for example. What is the best method to do that? Down below is my function.

```
public void loadFileRecursiv(String pathDir)
{
    File fisier = new File(pathDir);
    File[] listaFisiere = fisier.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length; i++)
    {
        if(listaFisiere[i].isDirectory())
        {
            loadFileRecursiv(pathDir + File.separatorChar + listaFisiere[i].getName());
        }
        else
        {
            String cuExtensie = listaFisiere[i].getName();
            int pos = cuExtensie.lastIndexOf(".");
            String nume = cuExtensie.substring(0, pos);
            String acronimBanca = nume.split("_")[0];
            String tipAct = nume.split("_")[1];
            String dataActString = nume.split("_")[2];

            SimpleDateFormat old = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat newPattern = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            String dataFormatata = null;

            try
            {
                dataFormatata = newPattern.format(old.parse(dataActString));
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //String denBanca = inlocuireAcronim(acronimBanca);

            processFolder(acronimBanca, acronimBanca); 
            insertData(listaFisiere[i], nume, acronimBanca, tipAct, dataFormatata);

            System.out.println("AICI =========== " + pathDir + File.separatorChar + listaFisiere[i].getName());
            moveFile(pathDir + File.separatorChar + listaFisiere[i].getName(), "/u02/ActeConstitutive/Mutate/");

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `File` - it's an outdated class, and there are better solutions in `java.nio`, and have been for many years now. Try one of the `walkFileTree` methods in [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to use a Set containing the folders you want to skip.

```
// get the folders you want to avoid and add them to your set

File Folder2 = new File(pathName);
Set<File> folderToSkip = new HashSet<File>();
folderToSkip.add(Folder2);

// add as many other folders you want to avoid
```

And then in the for loop, you can check whether or not you want to go inside this folder

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length; i++){
   if(!folderToSkip.contains(listaFisiere[i]){
       // do your stuff...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst your approach is recursive, the recursive part only applies to folder levels. You can skip over a loop operation via the

```
continue
```

keyword. Such as below:

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
 if(i == 0){
  continue;
 }
 System.out.println(i);
}
```

would skip over 0, the first operation, and output the following

```
1
2
3
4
```

[Example here](https://ideone.com/SHeMn6)

This allows you to build a more modular loop, in my opinion it *looks* better than

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
 if(i != 0){
  System.out.println(i);
 }
}
```

especially when nesting more conditionals or loops within, like so:

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
 if(i != 0){
  if(i != 0){
   if(i != 0){ 
    if(i != 0){
     if(i != 0){
       // stuff
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length; i++)
{
    if(listaFisiere[i].isDirectory())
    {
        if (!listaFisiere[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Folder2"))
            loadFileRecursiv(pathDir + File.separatorChar + listaFisiere[i].getName());
    }
    else
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

add an if statement at the first of method.

```
public void loadFileRecursiv(String pathDir)
{
    if(new File(pathDir).isDirectory() && skip(pathDir))
          return;
```

and make `skip` method which takes the path and checks that if you want to skip that folder or not; which returns a boolean. true means skip that.

Comment: skip method can be extended, so you can skip more than one folder, or list of folder. if you need any detail about it's implementation. just put a comment here.